# std::function Through type is not allowed

Tags: c++, c++11, testing

I Need to perform a unit test on AddToDB() API. Below is my Attemp but i get error when i create a callback with notify type 2 mention below

1. typedef std::function<bool(std::string)> strnotify;
2. typedef std::function<void(strnotify &)> notify;
3. bool AddToDB(notify data);

```
// callback for typedef std::function<bool(std::string)> strnotify;
   bool StringNotify(std::string){
     std::cout<<"String success";
     return true;
   }
   
   //  callback for typedef std::function<void(strnotify &)> notify;
   void StringObject(strnotify & obj){ // i get error here as type is not allowed
    std::cout<<"string obj success";
   }
   
   //Call to API 
   AddToDB(StringObject)
```

**I get error as type is not allowed.**

Comment: `strnotify` and `notify` are different, so you get an error if you use one where the other is expected.

Comment: Your code snapshot is not clear. I guess that `strnotify` return as a boolian type, but you are trying to catch as an object.

Comment: @ChrisDodd That my bad. I have corrected the typo error from the original post

Comment: @SakibAhammed I have update my question. Sorry for the typo mistake

Comment: @ChrisDodd  Can you please help to resolve the error. When i pass strnotify as parameter to StringObject method it say type is not allowed.

Comment: As corrected, there is no error in your program: https://godbolt.org/z/oPefP6  So the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code is work well, like say Chris Dodd, but only `AddToBase` function. You cannot create function for `std::function<void(strnotify &)> notify`, because you use reference to `std::functions<Type>` object.

This code work fine:

```
using strnotify = std::function<bool(std::string)>;
using notify = std::function<void(strnotify& )>;

bool AddToDB(notify data) {
// do something...
   return true;
}

int main() {

  auto fun = [](strnotify& s) -> void { /*do something */};
  auto fun2 = [](std::string s) -> bool {};

  //fun(fun2); // now work :(
  AddToDB(fun); // work!

  return 0;
}
```

But if you uncomment line in main function, you get error:

> gcc 10.2:
> 48:13:
> no match for call to '(main()::<lambda(strnotify&)>) (main()::<lambda(std::string)>&)'

So, how we can fix that? I have two ways for you:

1. do not use reference: `std::function<void(strnotify)> notify`;
2. firstly create `strnotify` object and use into function. Example in [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/s6qj7q).

And use `using` preferred than `typedef` please! Good luck!